# Android. Как скрыть информацию на экране выгрузки приложений из памяти?

Tags: android, activity, безопасность, memory, экран

На экране выгрузки приложений из памяти (который открывается нажатием одной из системных кнопок) можно посмотреть информацию, которая находится на последнем экране, на котором пользователь остановился в процессе пользования приложением. 
В моем приложении таким образом можно узнать некоторую конфиденциальную информацию.

**Вопрос:** можно ли скрыть превью экрана приложения и если да, то как это сделать?

**P.S.** Речь идёт про вот этот экран. Может для него есть название (желательно на английском) одним словом? :D

[image: Экран выгрузки приложений из памяти]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Превью экрана (*snapshot*) скрывается довольно просто, надо написать в `Activity.onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE); //prevents from taking screenshot
}
```

Правда, этот код имеет небольшой сайд-эффект - он попутно запрещает любой скриншот указанного `Activity` :)

По идее, православным способом является перегрузка метода:

```
@Override 
public boolean onCreateThumbnail(Bitmap outBitmap, Canvas canvas) { 
    return true; 
}
```

Но проблема с ним, в том, что в большинстве случаев он не работает - тому есть [баг-репорт](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36945159)

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за оперативный и чёткий ответ!